# how to show last 12 month date when I enter date/year for excel

Tags: excel, formula

i need help with excel,how to show last 12 month date when I enter date/year ,for example if I enter 02 jan 17 then the result will show me 03 feb 16, it show the date for last 12 month.

Answer (score 1):

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)+1)
```

(does give the right answer even when the current day is the last day of the month)